# Jquery Url reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i have an html code as follow

```
<ul id="userTabs" class="clearfix">

                <li class="selected"><a href="#profile">Profile Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="#test">test</a></li>

                <li><a href="#test2">test2</a></li>

                <li><a href="#test3">test3</a></li>

                <li><a href="#test4">test4</a></li>


    </ul>
```

previously i asked question on how to get an href value, now i need to know how to retain in same link when i reload a page.
THe JS code for click the above link are as follow

```
$("#userTabs li").click(function(){


      $("#userTabs li").removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
      href = href.replace("#","")
     //alert(href);
      //alert(href);
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?=$this->baseUrl('user/"+href+"')?>",
        data:{'page':href},
        dataType:"json",
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
          //alert('ok');
         //var contentHtml = data;
         $("#user_reviews_list").html('');
         $('#pagesuser').hide();
         $("#user_reviews_list").html(data);
         //alert(contentHtml);
        }
      });

    //alert('ok');
    });
```

now when i click on an link `test` the new content will be replaced with current content which are in `$("#user_reviews_list")` and my url changed to `http://localhost/user/john#test`, but if i reload the page, the content are no longer in #test but its back to original home content. How i can make sure that when i reload the content are suppose to be content of #test. ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var hash = document.location.hash;
    if(hash != '')
    {
        //load content
        //hack (just example, implement your logic here)
        $('#' + hash).parent().trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no easy answer to this, as it is considered as one of Ajax' major down-sides ( [see here about that.](http://www.jscripters.com/ajax-disadvantages-and-advantages/) ) that reloading/going back doesn't work as it should (without you doing a lot of work for it to work like that).

About making browser refresh work with ajax. Just google it, or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163610/ajax-and-the-browser-back-button), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381392/how-to-make-ajax-called-pages-to-reload-in-the-browser) or [here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/07/16/how-to-make-back-forward-and-reload-work-in-ajax-based-apps/)

Hope this helps!